# Is it bad practise to define all libraries in header file?

Tags: c++, libraries

If I have a piece of code, say `main.cpp` that requires the classes defined in `myheader.h` is it bad practise to then include all the libraries/headers required for `main.cpp` in the `myheader.h` file?

If so, why? Considering that `main.cpp` won't work without `myheader.h` any way.

Sorry if this question is a little simple - I'm just unsure of the common practise with separating across multiple files.

Comment: When you say `define all the libraries required for main.cpp in the myheader.h file` do you mean place the implementation of all the functions? Or maybe you mean include all the headers?

Comment: Also saying `define libraries` do you mean include libraries ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry wasn't too clear on the terminology - hope the edit clarifies things.

Comment: @KarenTsirunyan: Hello, brother :D

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Hello, brother :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you should include only those things that are needed in the current file. OK, so `main.cpp` uses `myheader.h` anyway, so why not include, say, `<iostream>` and other headers in `myheader.h` which are needed by `main.cpp`? Because tomorrow you will want to include `myheader.h` into `myOthercpp.cpp` which doesn't need `<iostream>` or other headers included in `myheader.h`, which is redundant and increases compilation time. So, whatever is needed in `main.cpp`, include in `main.cpp`.

There is an exception to this pattern which is called [precompiled headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header).

Comment: and if I need the same library in `main.cpp` and `myheader.h` should I include it in both files or just in `myheader.h`?

Comment: In case you need a certain library in `myheader.h` you have to include the library in it.But if you are including the `myheader.h` in your `main.cpp` it will be pointless to include the library either.

Comment: @user1331900: I slightly disagree with Karen. You shouldn't generally rely on a header file to include other header files for you, unless it's a standard header which guarantees to include another standard header. Otherwise keep every file self-sufficient. Include guards will prevent multiple inclusion anyway

Answer (score 0):

There are exceptions but generally it's good practice to not include headers inside headers.

### Compilation Speed

For example if you have a big library biglibrary.cpp / biglibrary.h

A class that depends on the big library to do some work myclass.h / myclass.cpp

And some code that depends on MyClass - main.cpp

---

main.cpp doesn't depend on biglibrary. It doesn't need to know anything about it. It only depends on myclass.h. If myclass.h includes biglibrary.h than compiling main.cpp has to parse biglibrary.h as well slowing down compilation.

### Cyclic Dependencies

Another problem is cyclic dependencies.
Say you have 2 classes A, B. A references B and B references A

Do you include a.h in b.h or b.h in a.h

A much cleaner solution is to just include the headers you need in your source files.

If code in the header requires a reference to a class that doesn't exist use a forward deceleration like here: http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/headerfileincludepatterns.htm